# SetFocus to a textbox wpf

Tags: wpf, textbox, setfocus

I want to  set focus to a textbox always. I am creating a application in wpf, in the search page there is a textbox i want to set focus to that textbox always, if the user clicks anywhere in the page the taxtbox should gain the focus. How to achieve this task.

Geetha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the solution of handling the `LostKeyboardFocus` and  `LostKeyboardFocus` and set the focus to the same element again using `Keyboard.Focus` method, you can find a lot of advices and other solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212999/stop-a-wpf-textbox-from-loosing-focus)