# Set focus of an element from its lost focus

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

For some reason focus a text box is need, so the focus is again set to the text box from its lost focus. This leads to stack over flow in the lost focus event.

Say,
 A Textbox and a button, now the focus is in Textbox and clicking on the button. In this case, need the focus to be in the textbox, so focus method of text box is invoked from its lost focus. This leads to stack over flow exception.

Why this happens and also how do the focus is retained in text box itself.

By handling PreviewKeyboardLostFocus of textbox, i have retained the Keyboard focus but how to retain the mouse focus in this?

Comment: You can call Focus() method for your TextBox when Button click is happened. Have you tried that ?

Comment: I need to handle things in Textbox lostfocus.. Focus should not move to button. While invoke the focus method in Textbox lostfocus its leads to stack over flow..

Comment: If you do not wish Button to get focus then set Focusable="False" for your Button.

Comment: @Nitesh: its not about the Button. it may have any other control, i need to focus in the textbox itself.. like am validating the textbox. so i wont allow the focus to others.

Comment: Add Code to your post

Comment: See the solution to this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212999/stop-a-wpf-textbox-from-losing-focus

Comment: The Stackoverflow is most likely caused by a cyclic call. Your method of Setting the Focus in the LostFocus Event somehow triggers the LostFocus Event again.

Comment: If you don't allow to Focus the Button then the Button cannot be clicked...

Comment: There is no notion of 'Mouse Focus' in WPF, just 'Keyboard Focus' and 'Logical Focus'. Check this [Focus Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768.aspx) article on MSDN. You may find that the `FocusManager.IsFocusScope` attached property mentioned on that page could help you.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you had handled SetFocus() Event, You might have handled something there leading to StackOverflowException.

Cheers!