# Retain focus in a UiElement(TextBox) on its Lost focus

Tags: c#, wpf, focus, uielement

[Set focus of an element from its lost focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17826238/set-focus-of-an-element-from-its-lost-focus)

With the continuation of above query, still its not able to retain the focus.

Is any other way to achieve this?

```
void OnPreviewLostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!Valid())
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        (sender as Control).Focus();
    }
}
```

With this code am not able to retain the focus..

Comment: This works for me. Are you talking about focus within the application or outside?

Comment: maybe try with the FocusManager

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager.setfocusedelement.aspx

Comment: @JustinPihony: with in the  Application only..

Comment: ok, what is the focus going from and to?

Comment: I have checked in snoop with event log. avent seen such handled events... but here am handling na.