# Is there any way to catch the mouse move event all over the desktop using c#?

Tags: c#

I need to update a label every time the pointer mouse moves, but not only in the form, i need to catch the move in all the desktop.

Is it possible?

Thank you.

Comment: I would say yes, by monitoring the windows messages, but just a hint at a guess.

Answer (score 1):

Do you just need the label to say "Mouse Moved" or is it dependent on where it moved to.  I guess either way you could user a Timer that goes off every once-in-a-while and checks the mouse x and y positions and compares them to the previous positions.

```
prevMouseX = MouseX;
prevMouseY = MouseY;
mouseX = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X;
mouseY = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y;
```

Then compare is mouseX = prevMouseX  etc...

Comment: I think this should works, but it is not the right way to do it, but thank you for the advice

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at Mouse Capture.  I'm not sure of all the circumstances you're working with, but take a look at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754010.aspx#mouse_capture) for an overview of mouse capture.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942357/what-does-it-mean-to-capture-the-mouse-in-wpf) also provides some information.