# What does Mouse.Capture mean?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0, mousecapture

Oops, I have a lot of questions that can't find answers to them in Google. Everybody is just using codes, and nobody explains their purposes. What does `Mouse.Captured` mean? And What does `Mouse.Capture()` do? And (sorry the last one) when `LostMouseCapture` occurs?

Comment: The docs explain it pretty simply.  "When an element captures the mouse, it receives mouse input whether or not the cursor is within its borders. The mouse is typically captured in this manner only during drag-and-drop operations, and retains capture until the drop action of the drag-and-drop operation occurs."  What is confusing about that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does it mean to "Capture the mouse" in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942357/what-does-it-mean-to-capture-the-mouse-in-wpf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, if you call [`Mouse.Capture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.capture.aspx) and pass in a input element, that input element (control) will always receive the mouse events, even if the mouse is outside of the bounds of the control.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.capture.aspx) is clear:

> When an element captures the mouse, it receives mouse input whether or not the cursor is within its borders.

`Mouse.Captured` just lets you see if an input element has the mouse captured, and `LostMouseCapture` occurs when the capturing stops.