# MouseMove impact on performance

Tags: c#, wpf

I am have MouseMove on multiple ListBoxes to check if user starts dragging between them and initiate it only if distance is greater than certain number.

Will it impact the performance as I add more features and animations?
Is it possible to have it send messages less frequently (without timer improvisations) or maybe bind event on MouseDown (but how to make sure I remove the event since MouseLeave is not reliable, MouseUp can be somewhere else, and also don't create multiple events)?

Answer (score 0):

Use `MouseDown` to intitiate "listening out" for your drag-like manipulation but you must capture the mouse so that the `MouseUp` event is caught if the button is released when no longer over the control.

See [What does it mean to "Capture the mouse" in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942357/what-does-it-mean-to-capture-the-mouse-in-wpf)