# mouse move is faster than redraw wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, shapes, mousemove, onmousemove

I'm defining shapes which inherit from class `Shape` and implement the 'Geometry' property.

Here's an example:

```
public class Landmark : Shape
{
    public override bool IsInBounds(Point currentLocation)
    {

        return (((currentLocation.X >= Location.X - 3) && (currentLocation.X <= Location.X + 3)) && ((currentLocation.Y >= Location.Y - 3) && (currentLocation.Y <= Location.Y + 3)));
    }

    protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
    {
        get
        {
            var landMark = new EllipseGeometry {Center = Location};

            Stroke = Brushes.Red;
            return landMark;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnIsMouseDirectlyOverChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        StrokeThickness = IsMouseDirectlyOver ? 12 : 6;
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = IsMouseDirectlyOver ? Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.ScrollAll : Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Arrow;
    }
    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            Location = e.GetPosition(this);
            InvalidateVisual();
        }
    }
}
```

When I click on the `Shape` and move my mouse, I expect the `Shape` to be redrawn in the new location - and it does work.

However, if I move the mouse "too" quickly, then I'm "leaving" the `OnMouseMove` event, and the `shape` gets stuck in the last position which the mouse pointer and the `Shape`'s location were in "sync".

Can such issue be solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [by capturing the Mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942357/what-does-it-mean-to-capture-the-mouse-in-wpf).

For that to work you must establish when to capture and when to release. Since you want this to work with the left mouse button, you can capture in `OnMouseDown` and release the mouse in `OnMouseUp`.